# Resize div to fill 100% of screen and not make a scroll bar

Tags: javascript, css

I got a menu on the left underneath my header of 150px in height and I am trying to make the menu fill the remaining space of the screen in height without getting a scrollbar.

Currently I got the following script to substract the menu from the div:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('#left_menu').height($(window).height() - 150 + 'px');
        $('.inner_contentwrapper').height($(window).height() - 150 + 'px');
    });
});
```

When I refresh the page the menu is still strechted too far, but if I open firebug and closes it the two divs adjusts and the scroll bar disapears.

Someone know how to make this run at page load?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not doing this with styles?

Comment: how would anyone be able to help you when they don't know what #left_menu and .inner_contentwrapper are ... I suggest creating a jsfiddle with you problem. But at first glance you appear to be putting the same height on two elements.

Comment: The problem is that I got a header on the top of my page, and when I use height:100% on the menu underneath the header the menu is too long.. It goes outside of the browser window and I get a scroll bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working after you open firebug b/c the window is resizing. In your code, you never actually call your resize when the document's ready. I think you really want:

```
var reHeight = function(){
  $('#left_menu').height($(document).height() - 150 + 'px');
  $('.inner_contentwrapper').height($(document).height() - 150 + 'px');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).resize(reHeight);
  reHeight();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the css for the div you don't want a scroll bar.
like this

```
$('#left_menu').css('overflow', 'visible')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could base your new sizes off the window size not the document size(which is possibly going to be larger than your window)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).resize(function(){
   $('#left_menu').height($(window).height() - 150 + 'px'); // why are you subtracting 150? might want to remove that...
   $('.inner_contentwrapper').height($(window).height() - 150 + 'px');
  });
})
```

;

Comment: Hmm, stille the same issue.. It works after I open firebug.. I am substracting 150px because of my top header that is 150px in height.